# merge three json object into one using java

Tags: java, json, ejb-3.0

i have these three json objects :

```
object = [{name: "Mary", car: "Fiat"}];
owner= [{firstName: "Mack", lastName: "jack"},{firstName: "Steve", lastName: 
"martin"}];
children= [{firstName: "toto", lastName: "jack"},{firstName: "titi", lastName: 
"martin"}];
```

I'm using JAVA, what i want to do is merge the three objects to get one object like this :

```
[{"name": "Mary", "car": "Fiat",
"owner":[{"firstName": "Mack", "lastName": "jack"},{"firstName": 
"Steve","lastName": "martin"}],
"children":[{"firstName": "toto", "lastName": "jack"},{"firstName": "titi", 
"lastName": "martin"}]
}]
```

any help please !

Comment: how you are trying to merge ? What is your unique key over here ?

Comment: Just use a POJO then convert to JSON object once all data processing is done.

Comment: Procedure: 1) use JSON library to parse JSON to give you `JSONObject` instances.  2) merge objects, 3) unparse using JSON library.

Comment: @ Stephen C , could you give me an exemple of JSON library to parse JSON to give you JSONObject

Comment: Erm ... you can find examples using Google.  Please do some research for yourself.   (Yes ... I could do your research for you, but if you learn to do it yourself you will be better off in the long run.  I suggest you start by searching for "json library java" ... and see what that gives you.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to read your json file and create a new one with changes in the new JSON structure, i will suppose that you already know how to extract data from a JSON file and i will leave this code example here showing how you can use JSON.Arrays for your purpose.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class jsonClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonTempObject1 = new JSONObject();
    jsonTempObject1.put("name","Mary");
    jsonTempObject1.put("car","Fiat");
    jsonArray1.add(jsonTempObject1);

    JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonTempObject2 = new JSONObject();
    jsonTempObject2.put("firstName","Mack");
    jsonTempObject2.put("lastName","Jack");
    jsonArray2.add(jsonTempObject2);

    jsonObject.put("object", jsonArray1);       
    jsonObject.put("owner", jsonArray2);

    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
    }
}
```

You will have the following result:

```
{
"owner":[{"firstName":"Mack","lastName":"Jack"}],
"object":[{"car":"Fiat","name":"Mary"}]
}
```

Comment: thank you @Elhoussine Zennati for your time of writing this, but the problem is,the exemple above its just an exemple, i want to do that dynamically without specify the value of the fields, because in my real objects i have almost 9 object must be merged into one json object, like mentioned above

Comment: You can use what i gave you , instead of specifying a String you can specify a value , something like jsonTempObject2.put(Value1,Value2); instead of "name" and "Mary". Also this code can be run on a loop , so that all of your elements gets added automatically, i don't have enough time to write it for you , but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
JSONObject Obj1 = (JSONObject) jso1.get("Object1");
JSONObject Obj2 = (JSONObject) jso2.get("Object2");
JSONObject combined = new JSONObject();
combined.put("Object1", Obj1);
combined.put("Object2", Obj2)
```

Comment: what jso1 and jso2 are ?